# Unmet dependency installing Nemo

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, nemo

I am trying to install on a fresh 14.04 system from the [Webupd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo). The main `nemo` package is failing to install with this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nemo
[sudo] password for lads: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nemo : Depends: nemo-data (= 1.8.4-1.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: nemo-fileroller but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However, the `nemo-data` package is installed and matches the required version:

```
$ apt-cache show nemo-data
Package: nemo-data
Source: nemo
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Installed-Size: 309
Maintainer: Jacob Zimmermann <ppa@jzimm.net>
Architecture: all
Version: 2.8.4-1~webupd8~trusty01
Replaces: nemo (<< 2.3)
Suggests: nemo
Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend, python2.7
Breaks: nemo (<< 2.3)
Filename: pool/main/n/nemo/nemo-data_2.8.4-1~webupd8~trusty01_all.deb
Size: 63218
MD5sum: d1bc65a62f2a8b6ce40d1a1bc572a92b
SHA1: 33dcbd960711b9ec114855812601fb8cd02cb058
SHA256: 252e8f09408d65a3fa1dd12dd4831af7cf81bef81425386d6e0c850ee792a54f
Description-en: File manager and graphical shell for Unity (data files)
 Nemo is the official file manager for the Cinnamon desktop. It allows
 to browse directories, preview files and launch applications associated
 with them. It is also responsible for handling the icons on the Cinnamon
 desktop. It works on local and remote filesystems.
 .
 This package contains pictures, localization files and other data
 needed by nemo.
Description-md5: 02a390092aabc879823f7e943d7aad23
Original-Maintainer: Linux Mint <root@linuxmint.com>

Package: nemo-data
Priority: optional
Section: universe/misc
Installed-Size: 3741
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Nicolas Bourdaud <nicolas.bourdaud@gmail.com>
Architecture: all
Source: nemo
Version: 1.8.4-1.1
Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend, python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
Suggests: nemo
Filename: pool/universe/n/nemo/nemo-data_1.8.4-1.1_all.deb
Size: 479372
MD5sum: 214953fff1daac66e2e0eaf82c77944a
SHA1: 38e4f4407892416a263ceef1fbddc15252b39e5b
SHA256: f3c845a37e82583a7dec5e47d8fd76bb94a9ec84802de3ae30fdffc9226b54f8
Description-en: File manager and graphical shell for Cinnamon (data files)
 Nemo is the official file manager for the Cinnamon desktop. It allows
 to browse directories, preview files and launch applications associated
 with them. It is also responsible for handling the icons on the Cinnamon
 desktop. It works on local and remote filesystems.
 .
 This package contains pictures, localization files and other data
 needed by nemo.
Description-md5: 9d6fd03be1bc86aa86ee0d95ef77a087
Homepage: http://www.github.com/linuxmint/nemo/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

I tried the basic tricks, but the system is not reporting any broken packages or other obvious issues that could eventually prevent `nemo` from installing:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What is going wrong here? Any hints on the cause of this or how to identify it?

**Update**: The output [required by Thomas W.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700149/unmet-dependency-installing-nemo#comment1026297_700149):

```
$ apt-cache policy nemo nemo-data
nemo:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.8.4-1.1
  Version table:
     1.8.4-1.1 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/universe armhf Packages
nemo-data:
  Installed: 2.8.4-1~webupd8~trusty01
  Candidate: 2.8.4-1~webupd8~trusty01
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.4-1~webupd8~trusty01 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo/ubuntu/ trusty/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.8.4-1.1 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/universe armhf Packages
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of this command: `apt-cache policy nemo nemo-data`

Comment: Have you tried installing the needed dependency `sudo apt-get install nemo-data` then it should print an error as to why it doesn't want to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your error message

```
nemo : Depends: nemo-data (= 1.8.4-1.1)
```

But the output of `apt-cache policy nemo-data` shows

```
nemo-data:
  Installed: 2.8.4-1~webupd8~trusty01
  Candidate: 2.8.4-1~webupd8~trusty01
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.4-1~webupd8~trusty01 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo/ubuntu/ trusty/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.8.4-1.1 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/universe armhf Packages
```

Means, the package manager can't install automatically the right version (`aptitude` could do that **;)**).

Run

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-data=1.8.4-1.1
```

to install the needed version.

Why? The Webupd8 PPA contains a `nemo-data` package for `armhf`, but currently not the matching `nemo` package for `armhf`.

Comment: Thanks A.B., it is all clear now. I was relying only on the `show` command, that is not explicit on the version installed. Is this version mismatch at the PPA a bug or a feature?

Comment: It's not a bug, but you should report the problem. It's a problem in the build process in the PPA. You should report the problem.